# Create options menu on bottom of screen, no action bar

Tags: android, android-optionsmenu

I've seen similar questions, but most solutions revolve around a split actionbar. I don't think this is possible in my app, as my theme is `Theme.Material.Light.NoActionBar`.

[Here](http://www.androidpolice.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/nexus2cee_clock-background-01.png) is an example of what I would like to do. The overflow menu is located on the bottom-right, and when clicked, a `ListView` opens similar to the normal options menu, [example seen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IFw5R.png).

I'm not sure if I can use native functions like `onCreateOptionsMenu` and `onOptionsItemSelected`. How can I get around having no actionbar? Would nested fragments work?

The layout of my app is fragments inside a `ViewPager`. The code for my overflow menu button is straight-forward, but I don't know how to open a `ListView` in the `onClick` method:

```
mSettingsButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.settingsButton);
mSettingsButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {

    }
});
```

I'd appreciate any advice or examples. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [ListPopupWindow](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListPopupWindow.html) for ListView by button

For example:

```
ListPopupWindow popup = new ListPopupWindow(SomeActivity.this);
popup.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(SomeActivity.this,R.layout.list_item, someSettings));
popup.setAnchorView(settingsButton);
popup.setWidth(300);
popup.setHeight(400);

popup.setModal(true);
popup.setOnItemClickListener(SomeActivity.this);
settingsButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        popup.show();
    }
});
```

Comment: Do you know how I can anchor it slightly lower? With `setAnchorView(mSettingsButton)`, it opens above the button. Ideally, I'd like to have it open over the button, like in the image above.

Comment: I have tried `mListPopupWindow.setVerticalOffset(0)`, but that does not seem to change anything. Setting a negative value works. [Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListPopupWindow.html#setInputMethodMode(int))

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Toolbar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toolbar.html) class and style / position it however you want on the screen.

For example

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
android:id=”@+id/my_awesome_toolbar”
android:layout_height=”wrap_content”
android:layout_width=”match_parent”
android:minHeight=”?attr/actionBarSize”
android:background=”?attr/colorPrimary” />
```

After that, use

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_awesome_toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

to set that as your main actionbar. The `onCreateOptionsMenu` and other actionbar related functions will work as expected. Make sure you disable the default actionbar in your theme as well.